# Is the const overload of begin/end of the range adapters underconstrained?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, std-ranges

In C++20, some ranges have both `const` and non-`const` `begin()/end()`, while others only have non-`const` `begin()/end()`.

In order to enable the range adapters that wraps the former to be able to use `begin()/end()` when it is `const` qualified, some range adapters such as [`elements_view`](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.elements.view), [`reverse_view`](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.reverse) and [`common_view`](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.common.view) all provide constrained `const`-qualified `begin()/end()` functions, for example:

```
 template<view V>
   requires (!common_­range<V> && copyable<iterator_t<V>>)
 class common_view : public view_interface<common_view<V>> {
  public:
   constexpr auto begin();
   constexpr auto end();

   constexpr auto begin() const requires range<const V>;
   constexpr auto end()   const requires range<const V>;
};

template<input_­range V, size_t N>
  requires view<V> && has-tuple-element<range_value_t<V>, N>
class elements_view : public view_interface<elements_view<V, N>> {
 public:
  constexpr auto begin();
  constexpr auto end();

  constexpr auto begin() const requires range<const V>;
  constexpr auto end()   const requires range<const V>;
};
```

The `begin() const/end() const` will only be instantiated when `const V` satisfies the `range`, which seems reasonable.

But only one simple constraint seems to be insufficient. Take `common_view` for example, it requires that `V` is not a `common_range`. **But when `V` is not a `common_range` and `const V` is a `common_range`** (I know that such a range is extremely weird, but in theory, it can exist, [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/h9hKPWrcT)):

```
#include <ranges>

struct weird_range : std::ranges::view_base {
  int* begin();
  const int* end();

  std::common_iterator<int*, const int*> begin() const;
  std::common_iterator<int*, const int*> end()   const;
};

int main() {
  weird_range r;
  auto cr = r | std::views::common;
  static_assert(std::ranges::forward_range<decltype(cr)>); // ok
  cr.front(); // ill-formed
}
```

In the above example, `const V` still satisfied the `range` concept, and when we apply `r` to `views::common`, its `front()` function will be ill-formed.

The reason is that `view_interface::front() const` will still be instantiated, and the `common_iterator` will be constructed inside the `begin() const` of `common_view`, this will cause a hard error to abort the compilation since `const V` itself is `common_range`.

Similarly, we can also create a weird range based on the same concept to make the `front()` of `views::reverse` and `views::keys` fail ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/6dn7j5Kof)):

```
#include <ranges>

struct my_range : std::ranges::view_base {
  std::pair<int, int>* begin();
  std::pair<int, int>* end();

  std::common_iterator<int*, const int*> begin() const;
  std::common_iterator<int*, const int*> end()   const;
};

int main() {
  my_range r;
  auto r1 = r | std::views::reverse;
  static_assert(std::ranges::random_access_range<decltype(r1)>); // ok
  r1.front(); // ill-formed

  auto r2 = r | std::views::keys;
  static_assert(std::ranges::random_access_range<decltype(r2)>); // ok 
  r2.front();  // ill-formed
}
```

So, is the `const` overload of `begin()/end()` of the range adapters underconstrained, or is the definition of `weird_range` itself ill-formed? Can this be considered a standard defect?

---

This question is mainly inspired by the [LWG 3592](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3592), which states that for `lazy_split_view`, we need to consider the case where the `const Pattern` is not `range`, and then I subsequently submitted the [LWG 3599](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3599). When I further reviewing the `begin() const` of other range adapters, I found that most of them only require `const V` to be `range`, this seemingly loose constraint made me raise this question.

In order to enable the range adapters' `begin() const`, theoretically, the constraints for `const V` should be exactly the same as `V`, which means that the [long list of constraints](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.elements.view) on `V`, such as `elements_view`, needs to be replaced with `const V` instead of only constraints `const V` to be a `range`.

But in fact, it seems that the standard is not interested in the situation where the iterator and sentinel types of `V` and `const V` are very different.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Recent SG9 discussion on [LWG3564](https://wg21.link/LWG3564) concluded that the intended design is that `x` and `as_const(x)` should be required to be substitutable with equal results in equality-preserving expressions for which both are valid. In other words, they should be "equal" in the [concepts.equality] "same platonic value" sense. Thus, for instance, it is not valid for `x` and `as_const(x)` to have entirely different elements.

The exact wording and scope of the rule will have to await a paper, and we'll have to take care to avoid banning reasonable code. But certainly things like "`x` is a range of pairs but `as_const(x)` is a range of ints" are not within any reasonable definition of "reasonable".